# Use a uint32_t to store four separate uint8_t values

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, unsigned-integer

I want to use a `uint32_t` to store 4 separate `uint8_t` values, and be able to read/write each of them individually.

Is it safe to do either of the following to set the value of each 8-bit range, and if so, which is better (faster, more portable)? I am not necessarily trying to set them all at once, I am only illustrating how to set each 8-bit value at any point in time.

```
uint32_t x = ...;
```

**Option 1**:

```
((uint8_t *)(&x))[0] = a;
((uint8_t *)(&x))[1] = b;
((uint8_t *)(&x))[2] = c;
((uint8_t *)(&x))[3] = d;
```

**Option 2**:

```
x = (x & 0xFFFFFF00) | (uint32_t) a;
x = (x & 0xFFFF00FF) | (uint32_t) b << 8;
x = (x & 0xFF00FFFF) | (uint32_t) c << 16;
x = (x & 0x00FFFFFF) | (uint32_t) d << 24;
```

Comment: Personally, I would eschew both these methods and use a union composed of a `uint32_t` and a `uint8_t[4]`

Comment: You do not need any of those `&` operations. The Option 2 i safe. The option one is not. Thew union method is good if you know your endianes

Comment: Ideally I would like to do this without having to consider endianness. Is that possible?

Comment: Option 1 assumes little endian byte ordering. Occam's razor would suggest a variant of option 2 since it makes less assumptions.

Comment: Bit-shifting is endian agnostic.

Comment: Is this question only about the operation "pack 4 bytes into uint32_t" or about any "replace byte inside uint32_t"?

Comment: Since the edit, comments don't make sense. The first line of option 2 should be `x = a;` without OR.

Comment: @harold I want to represent four different 8-bit values, but I must use a 32-bit type to store them.

Comment: @rtheunissen replace `x |= (uint32_t) a;` with `x = (uint32_t) a;`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts wouldn't that clear the other three 8-bit values that may already be set?

Comment: But you haven't already set them. What you would get is a preservation of any bits that happen to be alreay set.

Comment: Why does it matter what may already be set? Isn't the point to overwrite it?

Comment: I don't want to set the value of x, I just want to set a particular 8-bit range within x.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have already set them earlier - can't assume that a is 0.

Comment: @rtheunissen the question as evidenced from comments is different from the question as asked. I suggest you edit it appropriately.

Comment: This is confusing now: the question says "I want to use a uint32_t to store 4 separate uint8_t values." You can store exactly 4 8-bit values in a 32-bit field, so what it there to preserve?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.. o/

Comment: @WeatherVane I want to read/write to the uint32_t over time, so setting any of the 8-bit fields should not affect the other three.

Comment: Oh I see: that's why you mask off those 8 bits before ORring.

Comment: @WeatherVane correct, sorry again for not being clear enough about that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial revision had a correct <s>albeit roundabout</s> approach for option 2, which was

```
// a, b, c, and d are of initialized and of type uint8_t
uint32_t x = ...;
x = (x & 0xFFFFFF00) | (uint32_t) a;
x = (x & 0xFFFF00FF) | (uint32_t) b << 8;
x = (x & 0xFF00FFFF) | (uint32_t) c << 16;
x = (x & 0x00FFFFFF) | (uint32_t) d << 24;
```

This revision for option 2 is wrong:

```
uint32_t x = ...;
x |= (uint32_t) a;
x |= (uint32_t) b << 8;
x |= (uint32_t) c << 16;
x |= (uint32_t) d << 24;
```

Even when `x` is initialized it's still wrong because you're not *setting* the 8 bit ranges, you're *ORing* them.

The correct approach would be

```
// a, b, c, and d are of initialized and of type uint8_t
uint32_t x = (uint32_t) a;
x |= (uint32_t) b << 8;
x |= (uint32_t) c << 16;
x |= (uint32_t) d << 24;
```

Or more succinctly

```
// a, b, c, and d are of initialized and of type uint8_t
uint32_t x =
    (uint32_t) a
  | (uint32_t) b << 8
  | (uint32_t) c << 16
  | (uint32_t) d << 24;
```

The issue with option 1 is that it assumes the endianness of `uint32_t` to be LSB first and is therefore not a portable solution.

---

After receiving clarification about the question you're asking, your initial revision (the first code block in this answer) is the correct approach. It leaves the remaining 24 bits untouched while setting a particular 8 bit range to the `uint8_t` value on the RHS.

Comment: x is initialized, and the assignments were all examples of setting each 8-bit range.

Comment: I meant for `x = ...` to imply that it has some existing value.

Comment: @M.M yes but it clears and sets each 8 bit range with each individual assignment. By the end of the code block `x` no longer remains with any uninitialized bits.

Comment: I understand that, sorry. My intention was to illustrate a way to set each range individually, not necessarily all four sequentially.

Comment: @rtheunissen if `x` had a non-zero value initially, the result of your option 2 would result in `initial_x | a | b << 8 | c << 16 | d << 24`, which I assume is not what you want.

Comment: I am not necessarily setting all four of them, I was only trying to show how I _might_ set any one of them at any time.

Comment: @M.M I have updated the question to be more descriptive for the next person that comes along. I realize that many comments do not make sense now.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts if `x` were uninitialized then all of it is undefined behaviour, you can't partially "initialize" something bit by bit

Comment: @M.M you are correct. I've made modifications to my answer that remove any assumptions about x being uninitialized since that has already been clarified in the question. As a point of interest though, I'd be curious if any optimization setting on any existing compiler would be willing to remove or modify the logic for those compound assignments on the basis that `x` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Universal function (for pos8 16 and 24) :

```
uint32_t setb(uint32_t val, uint8_t a, int pos)
{
    val &= ~(0xffUL << pos);
    val |= (uint32_t)a << pos;
    return val;
}
```

If you do not like shifts:

```
uint32_t f(uint8_t a, uint8_t b,uint8_t c,uint8_t d) {    
      return a + 0x100UL * b + 0x10000UL * c + 0x1000000UL * d;
 }
```

any good optimizing compiler will generate very efficient code:

gcc ARM

```
f:
        add     r0, r0, r2, lsl #16
        add     r0, r0, r3, lsl #24
        add     r0, r0, r1, lsl #8
        bx      lr
```

clang x86

```
f:                                      # @f
        shl     esi, 8
        lea     eax, [rsi + rdi]
        shl     edx, 16
        or      eax, edx
        shl     ecx, 24
        or      eax, ecx
        ret
```

Only on very small micros I would recommend the union way

```
uint32_t g(uint8_t a, uint8_t b,uint8_t c,uint8_t d) 
{    
    union
    {
        uint32_t v32;
        uint8_t v8[4];
    }x = {.v8[0] = a, .v8[1] = b, .v8[2] = c, .v8[3] = d};
    return x.v32;
}
```

as it easier for it to optimize:

```
__zero_reg__ = 1
f:
        push r16
        push r17
        ldi r25,lo8(0)
        ldi r26,lo8(0)
        ldi r27,hi8(0)
        add r24,r22
        adc r25,__zero_reg__
        adc r26,__zero_reg__
        adc r27,__zero_reg__
        ldi r21,lo8(0)
        subi r20,lo8(-(8))
        sbci r21,hi8(-(8))
        rjmp 2f
1:      lsl r24
        rol r25
        rol r26
        rol r27
2:      dec r20
        brpl 1b
        ldi r19,lo8(0)
        subi r18,lo8(-(16))
        sbci r19,hi8(-(16))
        rjmp 2f
1:      lsl r24
        rol r25
        rol r26
        rol r27
2:      dec r18
        brpl 1b
        mov r19,r24
        clr r18
        clr r17
        clr r16
        mov r22,r16
        mov r23,r17
        mov r24,r18
        mov r25,r19
        pop r17
        pop r16
        ret
g:
        push r16
        push r17
        mov r25,r18
        mov r17,r22
        mov r22,r24
        mov r23,r17
        mov r24,r20
        pop r17
        pop r16
        ret
```